# How to access a target directory using bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I am relatively new to shell scripting. I am writing a script to compress all the files in current and target directory. I have found success in compressing the files of a current directory but I'm unable to write a script for compressing files in a target directory can anyone guide me?

I want to do something like this

```
% myCompress -t /home/users/bigFoot/ pdf ppt jpg
```

Comment: Like this maybe `cd /path/to/target && myCompress ...`

Comment: what hvae you tried so far?

Comment: Show us `myCompress`

Comment: #!/bin/bash
if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then
 echo "This shell script compress files with a specific extensions"
 echo "Call Syntax: compress <extension_list>"

 exit

 fi
for ext in $*; do
 for file in `ls *.$ext`; do
  gzip -k $file
 done
done

Answer (score 0):

## next time try to spread your code (it will make it easier to answer):

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then 
     echo "This shell script compress files with a specific extensions" 
     echo "Call Syntax: compress <extension_list>" 
     exit 
fi
for ext in $*; do 
    for file in ls *.$ext; do
          gzip -k $file 
    done 
done
```

## Mistakes made

`1)` `$*` - all  args coming after command - so.... **-t** and **path** are not **$ext** variables

`2)` `ls *.$ext` is red in loop as 2 strings `"ls and *.$ext"`  should be written as **`$(ls *.$ext)`** to get ls command executed

## My script for your request

```
#!/bin/bash

script_name=`basename "$0"`
if [[ $# == 0 ]]; then 
     echo "This shell script compress files with a specific extensions" 
     echo "Call Syntax: $script_name <dirctories_list> <extension_list>" 
     exit 
fi

# check if $1 is a directory
path=". "
file_type=""
for check_type in $* ; do
     if [[ -d $check_type ]]; then 
       path=$path$check_type" "
     else
       file_type=$file_type"*."$check_type" "
     fi
done

echo paths to gzip $path
echo files type to check "$file_type" 

for x in $path; do
    cd $x
    for file in $(ls $file_type); do
           gzip  $file 
    done 
    cd -
done
```

## Explanation

1) `basename "$0"` - get scripts name - it is more generic for usage - in case you change script's name

2)  `path=". "` - variable hold a string of all directories to be compressed, your request is to run it also on current directory `". "` 
    `file_type=""` - variable hold a string of all extensions to be compressed in `$path` string

3) running a loop on all input ARGS and concatenate directories names to `$path` string and other file types to  `$file_type`

4) for each of the directories inserted to script:

`i.`   `cd $x` - enter directorie

`ii.`  `gzip` - compress all files with inserted extensions

`iii.` `cd -` - go back to base directories

## Check gzip

I'm not familiar with the **gzip** command , check that you have **-k flag**

Comment: thankx shaiki siegal, it worked. and apologies for adding the code like this. I'll take care next time